# multi-line yaml input to mustache template outputs as JSON

Tags: json, templates, yaml, mustache

I have the following shell snippet

```
inputs="ingress_test_inputs.yaml"
auth_annotations="    # type of authentication
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    # name of the secret that contains the user/password definitions
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
    # message to display with an appropriate context why the authentication is required
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: 'Authentication Required - foo'"
echo "---" >$inputs
echo "namespace: qa" >> $inputs
echo "auth_annotations: ${auth_annotations}" >> $inputs

echo "----- Ingress inputs (${inputs}) -----"
cat $inputs

echo 'apiversion: extenstions/v1beta
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: aname
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx-internal"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      add_header Content-Security-Policy      "frame-ancestors 'self'";
      {{{auth_annotations}}}
spec:
  rules:
    - host: bla-bla-bla.{{namespace}}.example.com' >ingress.mustache
echo "----- Raw Ingress (ingress.mustache): -----"
cat ingress.mustache

mustache $inputs ingress.mustache > ingress-1.0.yaml

echo "----- Will apply the following ingress: -----"
cat ingress-1.0.yaml
```

However, when I run this the output for auth_annotations seems to be converted into JSON format (with => in between elements and comma at the end) like this (see the line before spec: ) ...

```
----- Ingress inputs (ingress_test_inputs.yaml) -----
---
namespace: qa
auth_annotations:     # type of authentication
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    # name of the secret that contains the user/password definitions
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
    # message to display with an appropriate context why the authentication is required
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: 'Authentication Required - foo'
----- Raw Ingress (ingress.mustache): -----
apiversion: extenstions/v1beta
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: aname
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx-internal"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      add_header Content-Security-Policy      "frame-ancestors self";
      {{{auth_annotations}}}
----- Will apply the following ingress: -----
apiversion: extenstions/v1beta
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: aname
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx-internal"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      add_header Content-Security-Policy      "frame-ancestors self";
      {"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type"=>"basic", "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret"=>"basic-auth", "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm"=>"Authentication Required - foo"}
```

I would have expected my original YAML to be pasted into those lines intact. It even strips off the comments (which I don't really care about) however, this is not the behaviour I was expecting. Why does mustache treat multi-line input differently to single line input?

I have tried searching for a similar question, but have not been able to come up with an answer.

EDIT: Added a single line variable, for comparison of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here:

- Mustache has no idea whatsoever that `ingress.mustache` is a YAML file. It will not parse it as YAML and in fact assumes it is HTML (because it will escape HTML special chars with HTML entities).

  The problem that arises from this is that mustache is not aware of current indentation etc when it is prompted to insert your value, so it is unable to paste your YAML while keeping the relative structure intact by adding to the original indentation in your `$inputs`.
- Mustache uses YAML for input, but not for output. What you see is mustache's representation of the `auth_annotations` values. Mustache has parsed the YAML into an internal structure and has no idea that you want it to be rendered as YAML.
- The problem is not single-line vs multi-line, but simple content (scalar) vs complex content (mapping).

To be able to properly indent your variables, you have to walk over the structure with mustache and insert them piece via a section. However, mustache is not able to walk over mapping values, only over sequences. So what you need to do is to make your input a sequence that is iterable via mustache:

```
auth_annotations="    # type of authentication
    - {key: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type, value: basic}
      # name of the secret that contains the user/password definitions
    - {key: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret, value: basic-auth}
      # message to display with an appropriate context why the authentication is required
    - {key: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm, value: 'Authentication Required - foo'}"
```

Then, you can insert it by modifying your template, using a mustache section to iterate over your list:

```
echo 'apiversion: extenstions/v1beta
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: aname
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx-internal"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      add_header Content-Security-Policy      "frame-ancestors 'self'";
    {{#auth_annotations}}
    {{key}}: {{value}}
    {{/auth_annotations}}
spec:
  rules:
    - host: bla-bla-bla.{{namespace}}.example.com' >ingress.mustache
```

Comment: I put triple {{{ around the YAML, exactly so that it wouldn't assume it's HTML. Surely if it knows nothing about the output being YAML it should just paste it as plain text and not assume I want JSON? The indentation might be a bit messed up. I've tried using the bash version "mo" and this actually works as expected, so I think this is a bug in the Ruby version of mustache.

Comment: The thing is that afaik mustache does not define how complex values (mappings & sequences) are rendered. Since the YAML has already been parsed, it is not as easy as „pasting plain text“ since the value is now an in-memory structure and not just the text of the YAML node. Rendering YAML is a complex process, so it is understandable that mustache renders a simplified form – that is, btw, not JSON. In fact, if it was JSON, it would also be valid YAML since YAML is a superset of JSON. JSON does not have `=>`.

Comment: I just checked: What you get is Ruby rendering a *hash* (the native Ruby data structure which is used for parsing YAML mappings into). Also note that YAML in general is not round-tripping, because (among others) YAML defines that the order of keys in a mapping must not convey content information, so most implementations parse it into an unordered dict/hash/map. That means that even if mustache would render the structure as YAML, you would not be guaranteed to get your keys in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stripped down version of the script, which demonstrates the problem.

```
inputs="ingress_test_inputs.yaml"
auth_annotations="
    foo: bar baz
    sam: jam man"
echo "namespace: qa" > $inputs
echo "auth_annotations: ${auth_annotations}" >> $inputs

echo "----- Ingress inputs (${inputs}) -----"
cat $inputs

echo '---
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx/thing:
      another_thing:
      {{{auth_annotations}}}
spec:
  rules:
    - host: bla-bla-bla.{{{ namespace }}}.example.com' >ingress.mustache

echo "----- Raw Ingress (ingress.mustache): -----"
cat ingress.mustache

mustache $inputs ingress.mustache > ingress-1.0.yaml

echo "----- Will apply the following ingress: -----"
cat ingress-1.0.yaml
```

This gives the same problem as the original question that I posted.

```
----- Ingress inputs (ingress_test_inputs.yaml) -----
namespace: qa
auth_annotations:
    foo: bar baz
    sam: jam man
----- Raw Ingress (ingress.mustache): -----
---
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx/thing:
      another_thing:
      {{{auth_annotations}}}
spec:
  rules:
    - host: bla-bla-bla.{{{ namespace }}}.example.com
----- Will apply the following ingress: -----
---
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx/thing:
      another_thing:
      {"foo"=>"bar baz", "sam"=>"jam man"}
spec:
  rules:
    - host: bla-bla-bla.qa.example.com
```

However, if I replace "mustache" with "mo" which is the bash implementation, it works :-

```
----- Ingress inputs (ingress_test_inputs.yaml) -----
namespace: qa
auth_annotations:
    foo: bar baz
    sam: jam man
----- Raw Ingress (ingress.mustache): -----
---
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx/thing:
      another_thing:
      {{{auth_annotations}}}
spec:
  rules:
    - host: bla-bla-bla.{{{ namespace }}}.example.com
----- Will apply the following ingress: -----
namespace: qa
auth_annotations:
    foo: bar baz
    sam: jam man
---
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx/thing:
      another_thing:

spec:
  rules:
    - host: bla-bla-bla..example.com
```

To my mind this suggests a bug in the Ruby gem, as it doesn't handle YAML correctly when it's part of the output.